# Win32 API how to select LSB first or MSB first

Tags: windows, winapi, serial-port

I am trying to figure out how to select between sending the LSB or MSB first using WIn32 API (on com ports).

I have already managed to send/receive data (asynchronous) so this is not an issue. Is there no option to select between LSB/MSB first?

(I am using Code::Blocks, Not Visual Studio!)

Comment: Pick one, and just do it. No one will care what you picked, as long as it works.

Comment: I know, my MCU/software still works fine with whatever I pick. I just want to know where can I change this option

Comment: Winapi does not have an option to represent data with different byte order. Byte order is defined by computer architecture. If you want to change byte order when you send data over sockets you have to write additional code.

Comment: There is [htonl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-htonl) and friends in *winsock.h*, so you don't actually have to write the code.